# Genitive Saxon: Do you append apostrophe s ('s) after plurals and words ending with s?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Should the apostrophe and the **s** of genitive Saxon be used after plural forms or words ending with the letter **s**? For example:

> airplanes wings must be defrosted before taking off

or

> airplanes's wings must be defrosted before taking off

Comment: This is a simple question with a not-so-simple answer. I'm hoping an ELLer will give you a good one, but, in the meantime, you can see what [GrammarBook](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/apostrophes/apostrophes-with-words-ending-in-s/), the [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/apostrophe-catastrophe-part-two), the [CCC grammar pages](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/possessives.htm), the [Purdue Owl](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/621/01/), and our sister site [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073) have to say on the matter.

Comment: @J.R.♦: I disagree in the case of OP's specific example. The apostrophe is always written, but the genitive **s** isn't written *unless* it's enunciated in the spoken form. Since no-one would pronounce that extra **s** after possessive plural **airplanes**, the only credible orthography is *"The **airplanes'** wings must be defrosted"*. Except in practice most of us would simply use the singular without genitive as an "attributive noun" - as in *"**Tyre** pressures should be checked before a long journey"*.

Comment: I've always been a supporter of 'use one if you pronounce it, don't if you don't. Use a singular if it makes life easier.' too... Chris's house, kids' toys, airplane wings.

Comment: @Tetsujin But that rule isn't particularly helpful for non-native speakers, because you're left with the question of "when do you pronounce it?" which, as you've noted, is almost the same question.  (Not precisely the same, since practices differ slightly in speech and writing.)

Comment: Quirk et al's 1985 *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* has a nice chart on p.320.

Comment: @snailboat tbh, you're right - but most natives aren't too sure either & make it up as they go, using whichever seems easiest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pronounce the possessive form of 'case'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74308/how-do-i-pronounce-the-possessive-form-of-case)

Answer (score 3):

The s-genitive for plural nouns is relatively simple:

1 When the plural does not end in -s you add 's

- the children's teacher
- women's football

2 When the plural ends in -s you add only an apostrophe

- a ladies' hairdresser
- the teachers' room

More information here:

http://www.grammar.cl/rules/genitive-case.htm

Normally the s-genitive is not used with things (but it is possible in certain cases).

Normally you use the of-genitive with things. So you would say

- The wings of areoplanes/airplanes must be defrosted.

Or you use airplane (AmE) as compound element

- Airplane wings must be defrosted.

Comment: There is no rule that the s-genitive should not be used with things. It apparently wasn't in the King James Bible, but Shakespeare wrote *"It is the show and seal of **nature's** truth, 
Where **love's** strong passion is impress'd in youth",* *"His wonted sleep under a fresh **tree's** shade,"* and *"Unpeg the basket on the **house's** top, 
Let the birds fly."* And I believe that people have been using the 's genitive for things ever since. There is absolutely nothing wrong with *"aiplanes' wings"*.

Comment: And slightly more recently some English blokes wrote this song _a hard day's night_...