# How do you pronounce "herons'"? (plural possessive)

Tags: pronunciation, plural-forms, possessives

- Heron: Singular noun
- Herons: Plural of heron
- Herons': Possessive plural of heron

Do I pronounce it like "herons" or do I pronounce it like "heronses"?

There's only one 's', but there could be confusion between saying "This ball is the heron's." and "This ball is the herons'." if it were pronounced "herons" despite the difference in meaning.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Rstevoa! I guess the listener(s) will have to guess from the context. "Herons**es**" would remind me personally of Gollum's "[hobbits**es**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hobbitses)".

Comment: I pronounce it with a "z" - Hair-onz.

Comment: Pronounce it as you see it. There is no s's in any of your examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Herons'* is pronounced exactly the same as *herons* and *heron's*: in the International Phonetic alphabet, we can write it as /ˈhɛrənz/ (that's the "h" from *hot*, followed by the "err" from *error,* and the "ons" from *onions*).

For regular plural nouns, the rule for forming the possessive is as follows (quoted from the book [*Teaching Pronunciation: A Reference for Teachers of English to Speakers of Other Languages*](https://books.google.com/books?id=twC-H4a8VcYC&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=English%20plural%20possessive%20pronunciation&source=bl&ots=CmyWMkswtc&sig=EDpx7k-1Fo3gG5B-h93qeGhRrvU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuucCsuLLJAhUJ32MKHTEkBY4Q6AEIWDAI#v=onepage&q=English%20plural%20possessive%20pronunciation&f=false)):

> When the plural form of the noun ends in *-s* (or *-es*), an apostrophe is
>   placed after the plural inflection to indicate the possessive in
>   writing. Notice that with regular plural nouns, there is no phonetic
>   difference between the singular possessive and the plural possessive
>   modifier: *the girl̲s̲' books* (sounds like *the girl̲'s̲ books*), *the
>   neighbor̲s̲’ house* (sounds like *the neighbor̲’s̲ house*).

As mentioned in this related question ([Genitive Saxon: Do you append apostrophe s ('s) after plurals and words ending with s?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51237/genitive-saxon-do-you-append-apostrophe-s-s-after-plurals-and-words-ending-w)) in general, the written sequence *s's* corresponds to /zəz/, and the sequence *s'* corresponds to /z/ with only a single /z/ sound.

Usually it is not important to distinguish plural and singular here. If you do need to, you can reword the sentence; in this case, you might say something like "This ball belongs to the [heron/herons]" or "This ball came from the [heron/herons]."

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected - thanks @Sumelic.**
Although names such as *James* may be pronounced with an extra "es" (to form "James-es", for example), the possessive forms of both *heron* and *herons* are pronounced the same way, "herons". Due to the ambiguity resulting from the pronunciation, it would be advisable to use an alternate form such as "... of the heron" or "... of the herons" when you need to distinguish the singular possessive from the plural possessive.

Comment: This is just wrong. See discussion here ([Plural possessive - pronunciation](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/plural-possessive-pronunciation.1784632/)), and the rule in the book here ([Teaching Pronunciation: A Reference for Teachers of English to Speakers of Other Languages](https://books.google.com/books?id=twC-H4a8VcYC&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=English+plural+possessive+pronunciation&source=bl&ots=CmyWMkswtc&sig=EDpx7k-1Fo3gG5B-h93qeGhRrvU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuucCsuLLJAhUJ32MKHTEkBY4Q6AEIWDAI#v=onepage&q=English%20plural%20possessive%20pronunciation&f=false))

Comment: If by "wrong", you are referring to the hypothetical "classes-es" pronunciation, you might well be correct. However, that pronunciation is only used here as the basis for the objection. If you're objecting to my answer that *herons'* would classically be pronounced "herons-es", I can only say that usage is inconsistent. E.g. Cambridge dictionaries online considers *James'* to be pronounced "James-es", whereas other words aren't pronounced with the extra "es". Clarity and fluency of expression are more important (see: alternate form in my answer).

Comment: The pronunciation variant you are referring to is only ever an option for singular nouns ending in *s*, not for plural nouns. *Herons-es* is just as hypothetical and incorrect as *classes-es*.

Comment: @sumelic Having considered other plurals such as *girls' room* / *boys' room*, I concede your point. When it is important to distinguish the singular possessive from the plural possessive, though, I still maintain that it is best to use an alternate form like *of the class / classes*.

Comment: Obviously, if it's important to distinguish them, it clearly follows that an alternate form must be used.

Comment: @sumelic Answer edited. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Thanks for editing! Just a few more suggestions: the pronunciation you describe applies specifically to the possessive form of names such as *James* (so, *James's* or *James'*),  they "may be" pronounced with with an extra "es" (rather than "are"), and "of the herons" seems to me to only really sound natural attributively, not predicatively ("the ball of the herons" sounds OK, but *"this ball is of the herons" sounds bad to me).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32234/discussion-between-lawrence-and-sumelic).