# How to pronounce "Moderators's"?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives

If I want to use the plural of "moderator" and also add the apostrophe plus S, how do I pronounce it? How do native speakers pronounce it?

1. Moderators = **moderatorz**
2. Moderator**s's** = **moderatorziz** or just **moderatorz**?

A sentence is:

> "I always thought that **moderators's** decisions seemed fairly arbitrary." [(from Meta StackExchange)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136110/841781)

I guess **moderatorziz** is correct but it sounds weird to me. Do native speakers pronounce it as **moderatorziz**?

Comment: That’s not the rule for possession. The correct word is *moderators’.*   https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/51237/41273

Comment: @Laurel Please see the sentence I just added. If it is **moderators'**, then how do you "pronounce" it?

Comment: The moderators' decision. It is just pronounced like the plural noun: moderators. It's like any other possessive plural except for ones that end in z or s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the construct "s's" is not used here.  The plural possessive for "moderator" is simply "moderators'".  For example:

> "The moderators' instructions were helpful as we progressed along the
> journey."

*The pronunciation of **moderators** and **moderators'** is identical with the the meaning having to be discerned from the context.  In both cases there is a single 's' sound not a doubled sound like you have suggested.*

I'll note that even for native speakers the meaning can be unclear between "moderator's" and "moderators'" when speaking.  So it can be helpful to choose a different sentence structure to help convey your meaning.  For example:

> "There were several moderators along the journey and their
> instructions were helpful."

Comment: I actually chose this example for the sake of "pronunciation". I'm curious to know the pronunciation. ;-)

Comment: I covered that in my answer.

Comment: I upvoted and will accept it if no other answers were posted

Comment: @jwh20 Good answer.  I think Sphinx is requesting a clear, bulleted item that is easily extracted from your answer in addition to the valuable supporting information.  Something along lines of **Both are pronounced *moderators***.  Currently you only say they are pronounced the same but now how they are pronounced.

Comment: It's words ending in s or z that cause the issue. Not anything else. Jones and Fernandez.

Answer (score 2):

To me, *moderators's* is a misspelling. Therefore, if I were reading a text and came across the word *moderators's* in that text, I would ignore the misspelling and pronounce it as though it were written as *moderators'* (which is pronounced exactly the same as just *moderators*, with no apostrophe).

The same goes for other misspellings, too. If I were reading a text and came across the phrase "I was looking out the **widnow**," then that would clearly be a misspelling of "window," and so I would simply read that word as "window."

Comment: Thanks for this answer!