# Is the possessive of a name that ends in 's' pronounced differently if it refers to a group of people (like a band) instead of a single person?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, plural-forms, apostrophe, names

How do you think names that have the plural "s" should be pronounced when they get the apostrophe? I researched this on the web and I couldn't find any very reliable results. For example, how should these three words be pronounced?

- The Beatles'
- Red Hot Chili Peppers'
- Mr. Jingles'

Context: In case you don't know, The Beatles are a band, Red Hot Chili Peppers are also a band. "Jingles" is a last name that includes the plural "s". It is not a band name. I know that normally, when a plural word gets the apostrophe, you don't make a second /ɪs/ or /ɪz/ sound. For example, you don't say, /ɡɑɪzɪz/ when you say  "guys' ". But I think we might pronounce another /ɪs/ or /ɪz/ when we say the words I gave because names like "The Beatles" represent one singular band while they also represent the people in the band. When you say "Mr. Jingles" also it represents one person. So I thought it may be correct to pronounce the example words I gave as, "The Beatles + /ɪz/", "Red Hot Chili Peppers + /ɪz/", "Jingles + /ɪz/".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124034/discussion-on-question-by-fire-and-ice-is-the-possessive-of-a-name-that-ends-in).

Answer (score 0):

I would pronounce them with a *silent possessive*, i.e. not adding the /ɪz/, in the manner of [the answer linked by FumbleFingers.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267210/how-to-pronounce-moderatorss)

Comment: Are you ***sure***  Lynne Truss said that? Can you provide a verification link? I thought she knew what she was talking about, but that "modern / ancient name" distinction sounds like total garbage to me.

Comment: ***James*** (and to perhaps a lesser extent ***Charles***) are pretty "ancient" names. And it's effectively a stylistic choice whether to write/enunciate possessive **s** with them. All that matters is the orthography *should* match the pronunciation (but the possessive apostrophe itself is *always* written, even though it's not enunciated).

Comment: @Fumble I actually had it backwards, but [she did make the distinction](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Eats_Shoots_Leaves/e2ROR0qqFwwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=jesus), while also saying "these are matters of style and preference." And, following *Fowler's*, she described biblical names as "modern." https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv2Qs.png (An interesting typo there, I definitely recall reading "St James's Square" in my print copy.)

Comment: I can't follow your first link there, but does the png link definitely reflect Truss's own text? I don't understand *an exception is **always** made for Jesus* - as I've pointed out repeatedly, that one is ***optional***. If you write [***Jesus' disciples***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22jesus%27+disciples%22), you shouldn't enunciate the possessive 's'. But it's perfectly acceptable to make the stylistic choice to write [***Jesus's disciples***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22jesus%27s+disciples%22), in which case you *should also* enunciate the 's'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with you that the orthography should match the pronunciation: either we both write and pronounce the extra "s" (as is traditional, except with a small number of names) or we write a final apostrophe sans "s" and don't pronounce an extra "s".  However, surprisingly enough, there are some people (mainly in the US) who believe in omitting the extra "s" from the spelling and yet pronouncing it. An answer at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/565500/do-i-say-chriss-being-annoying-or-do-contractions-not-work-in-this-scenario/565519 advocates this strange system.

Comment: ALSO - I've just noticed something that would make me instantly reject anything relating to what that png claims. It gives the specific example **St Jame's Square**, which is ***rubbish**!* I can't believe anyone would have been so daft as to *deliberately* write that, but in a context specifically dealing with orthographic subtleties, it beggars belief that they couldn't properly proofread that one!

Comment: @rjpond: I'd be interested to know if you can find *anyone* (not just a "recognised authority") who would attempt to *actually defend* the idea of pronouncing the 's' but not writing it (as opposed to doing this out of carelessness). I have no problem with consistency down either path, and I can almost get my head around the idea that you might deliberately write the 's' but not pronounce it. But the "pronounce but don't write" permutation just sounds potty to me!

Comment: @Fumble yes, the screenshot is of the text at the link—it definitely is from Lynne Truss. **St Jame's Square** is assuredly a typo, as I mentioned; I do remember it being **St James's Square** in my book.

Comment: @randomhead: [The *majority* of writers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=St+James%27s+Square%2CSt+James%27+Square&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) include the optional 's'. But as that link shows, plenty of people *don't* write it. Of course, we've no way of knowing for sure how many people don't speak as they write, but obviously there's flexibility so far as *writing* goes.